# On it's own, my Verizon Droid Razr (recently with ICS), went into debug mode. How do I get it out of debug mode?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, motorola-droid, usb-debugging

This evening I took my phone out of my pocket and the screen was on and it was in debug mode.  I assume it is debug mode - there is a column of text right justified near the top of the screen that changes with time.  When my finger touches the screen a vertical and horizontal line appear and track my finger movement and there is a trail left showing where I moved my finger. Along the top of the screen there are fields which display info about the finger movement.  I am not a developer, but I assume this is debug mode.

My question is:  How can I get it out of debug mode?  HELP!!!

Comment: As you tagged your question usb-debugging: Did you check that option? It is usually found in your system settings with the devloper specific stuff in the apps section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have "{} Developer options" under Settings menu? If yes, go to Settings->Developer Options and uncheck the boxes under "Input", "Drawing" "Monitoring" sections.

I presume these should be not available with standard ROMs (i.e. produced by carrier/that come with phone).  In that sense, I am bit surprised on why you have it, unless you have CM's or other similar ROM.

Comment: You got it. I did have a developer menu and somehow while it was turned on in my pocket the following options got turned ok: pointer location, show touches, show screen updates, show CPU usage and force GPU rendering.

Comment: I absolutely have the standard Verizon Droid Razr. I bought it on the day it became available, 11/11/2011, and I was automatically upgraded to ICS several weeks ago, over the air on, I think, the first day Verizon released it. I have never tried to root it or change ROMs or anything?

Comment: Should I leave Force GPU rendering ON? That sounds like it would be faster. Is it safe and well tested?

Comment: I am sorry FrankH, I am not certainly clear enough to recommend, though I too have it set to ON ;-)

Comment: Regarding Force GPU rendering, you might want to read this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17731/force-gpu-rendering-in-ics-how-does-this-affect-system-performance in short, it's not an option you want to be turned on, unless you're debugging an app.