# Do ALL stock Verizon Droid RAZRs have the full Developer Optionc menu on System Settings?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, verizon, motorola-droid-razr

I have it on my Droid RAZR bought at Verizon on the 1st day available: 11/11/2011. It was recently updated over the air to Ice Cream Sandwich. I never rooted or installed custom ROMs. I do have a developer menu ( which caused this problem: [On it's own, my Verizon Droid Razr (recently with ICS), went into debug mode. How do I get it out of debug mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26917/on-its-own-my-verizon-droid-razr-recently-with-ics-went-into-debug-mode-ho)). Do all Verizon droid RAZRs have this menu item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtually all Android devices have the Developer options menu. This is stock Android; a carrier or device manufacturer would have to explicitly remove it. If they did, the hue and cry from actual Android developers would be very loud; some might even refuse to develop for such a device, which would have a negative impact on device sales.

In Ice Cream Sandwich, it's grown lots of extra options, as you've noticed.

The developer options are mostly useful to actual developers, though some of them are useful to power users. For instance, "USB Debugging" allows a user to control their Android from their PC with [adb](/questions/tagged/adb); that could be anything from [side-loading](/questions/tagged/side-loading) an [apk](/questions/tagged/apk) to [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) the device. Privacy fanatics will appreciate "Allow mock locations"; when this option is on they can use simple apps to generate false [geolocation](/questions/tagged/geolocation) data. And my personal favorite is "Stay awake" which prevents the phone from sleeping or blanking the display while it's on the charger.

If you're having a problem with these options getting enabled while the device is in your pocket, as in your other question, consider using a screen lock.

In Jelly Bean, developer options must be enabled explicitly and a warning dialog appears if you try to enable developer options. This will help prevent you from enabling them accidentally in your pocket.

Comment: Thanks! This was the only time they ever got enabled, so it ts not a continuing problem. I was just surprised they were there, I always thought a developer would have to do something special to get to those options.

Comment: Even non-developer power users may find the options interesting and useful.