# How to stop this type of service in Sony Xperia MT27i?

Tags: settings, sony-xperia

I have an Android 4.0.4 device Sony Xperia MT27i.
When this device connects in Mac then it looks like this.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

Some services are started and also it displays an unwanted screen.

I've searched all the settings and tried to stop this, but no success.
Please can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are due the debug settings enabled in Settings menu. Since I am not with any 4.0 device, I am unable to tell exactly what to be switched off.  Probably while switching on the USB debugging, you might have experimented with with other settings. Turn off all other than USB debugging to see these to go off.

Take a look at this [similar](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26917/on-its-own-my-verizon-droid-razr-recently-with-ics-went-into-debug-mode-ho/26920#26920) question with similar answer.